# What HTML/CSS/JS libraries can/should I use to get similar XAML functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, css, silverlight

So in Silverlight I've seen an app that had 4 windows together in a box shape. When you click on a window, the windows will rotate to the upper right corner and enlarge while the other 3 shrunk. Then if you click on the enlarged window again, all the windows would go back to their normal size. Now I know all of that can be done in Silverlight (w/XAML and Expression Blend). But what would I use in the HTML/CSS/JS libraries to get the same effect.

Another way of putting it is: if you wanted to have a website with heavy UI razzle-dazzle efects what HTML/CSS/JS libraries would you use or recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get a fair approximation of this type of functionality using the jquery UI layout plugin.  You will have to write some of your own javascript to get it to do exactly what you mention above, but the framework is definitely there

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

They have a great page with a lot of good demos to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery/jQueryUI. It is commonly used to manipulate DOM and has lots of adding. One of them be what you're looking for.